# Create lists in windows 7 phone

Tags: list, windows-phone-7

I am trying to add a page to my application which will show a list of top users of my app. Can anyone please suggest how to create this list component? Is there any way of creating a list or table view in windows 7 phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind data to ListBox easily.

Here's a demonstration project you can run using some xml packaged in the XAP, and LINQ.

[binding a Linq datasource to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72)

Comment: Thank alot Mick. That was great